# Component registration with .default is not working

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, laravel-mix

I have 2 projects (A and B) and some packages which should be used in both projects. In A the component registration works with .default, in the other however not. What exactly do I have to update to make it work in B?

included vue component like this:
`Vue.component('trm-vuetify-drawer', require('./components/DrawerApp.vue').default);`

In Project B I would have to remove .default to use it correctly. But I want to use .default since the components comes from a package.

There is no more code. Its registration is just not working.

Versions: 
Vue: 2.6.9
Vue-Template-Compiler: 2.6.9

I get the following error:

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: Are you using laravel-mix?

Comment: yes, i am using laravel-mix@2.0

Comment: You should provide more explanation. show your code...

Comment: There is not much code. But I added some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel Mix 2.0 you should not use `.default` yet. This is required in Laravel Mix 4.0 and later only.

Just change your code to:

```
Vue.component('trm-vuetify-drawer', require('./components/DrawerApp.vue'))
```

---

Or you can just update to Laravel Mix 4.0+ if you want to use `.default` everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. I've updated to laravel-mix 4.0.* since the registration comes from a package and I dont want to remove .default every time.

Comment: @PhilippBrosig Yes, sorry, forgot to add "or update to mix 4.0+" to my answer :)